# Gemfile.lock changing automatically on M3 Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile.lock

I am not running any commands to make changes. My Gemfile.lock continues to add a line automatically, and every time I undo it, the change is rewritten.

```
PLATFORMS
  arm64-darwin-22
  arm64-darwin-23 # this is the line being added
  x86_64-darwin-22
  x86_64-linux
```

Spring and Rails server are not running. Bundler version is 2.4.22.

Comment: Probably you have some processes that initialize your app. platform(S) — why don't commit this changes?

Comment: Sounds like you are the first person on the team to bundle on an M3 mac, so the lockfile is listing yours as a compatible platform. Either commit it or discard the changes if you don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with M2 Mac and the Visual Studio Code editor, I only closed and opened the editor code and this behavior was fixed.